# How to handle MySQL CommunactionException which occurs when database turns off when application is running

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Spring Boot Application uses `MySQL + C3p0 DataSource`.
This DataSource I use to work with **JDBC** and **JPA**(provider **Hibernate**).

In every **JDBC DAO layer method** I have try/catch **SQLException**. And this catch block **realy catch this** ***Communication Exception*** but..

But when I try so send requests more and more I start to have this stacktrace.

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

+ many details ..

And **finally** **I catch** in **SQLException catch block**:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

*Before this message* application looked like **It can't connect and It know It**.
It gives responses with 500 status code **very fast**.

*After this message* application looks like **It try to connect and can't understand that It can't**. In this case It gives responses **very slowly**.

After switching on the database, application works without restart.

Comment: Could you put the code of some of your DAO and your database conection configuration in Spring?

Comment: @JosemyAB of course, question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big stack trace might be printed by the web server on which your application is running. May not be from your code. You need to read about your web server on how to avoid such stack trace printing.